# problems with search interface in android app

Tags: android, search

Hi I am trying to create the search interface for an android app. I have followed the android developers tutorial but I'm still getting errors. I don't know where I have gone wrong, please help! I'm trying to integrate a search widget in the layout of my app. Below is what I have done so far:

Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amazonsearch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
            android:name="com.example.amazonsearch.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
           <!-- this is the searchable activity; it performs searches -->
    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    <!-- this activity enables the search dialog to initiate searches
         in the SearchableActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".OtherActivity" >
        <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.amazonsearch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the options menu from XML
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

        return true;
    }



}
```

SearchableActivity.java

```
package com.example.amazonsearch;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchresults);

        final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
        final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
            String searchKeywords = queryIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.i("YOU ENTERED", searchKeywords);
        }
    }
}
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

These are the following errors:

```
[2013-04-21 16:03:36 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for E:\Workspace\AmazonSearch\AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
[2013-04-21 16:03:36 - AmazonSearch] Error in an XML file: aborting build.


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
menu_search cannot be resolved or is not a field    MainActivity.java   /AmazonSearch/src/com/example/amazonsearch  line 28 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
options_menu cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /AmazonSearch/src/com/example/amazonsearch  line 24 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
searchresults cannot be resolved or is not a field  SearchableActivity.java /AmazonSearch/src/com/example/amazonsearch  line 15 Java Problem
```

Comment: Post your logcat trace.. or or post text if there are syntax errors

Comment: i've included the errors

Comment: Selecting a best answer will give incentive for people to give answers to your future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your searchable has two closing brackets. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: Thanks! Was dealing with the same problem. Glad that finally landed in this link.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well formed. Check for errors in XML. There is an extra closing >.  You have not given IDs to your XML elements it seems.