# Adding a search bar on the top of activity and showing results below in any Layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, searchbar

I want to create an `Activity` on the top of which there will be a `Search Bar`, and on the basis of the search I will query the database and show the result on the same `Activity` below. I might choose any kind of `layout` for showing those results. I am thinking of creating a `Canvas` to show results in formatted manner (like we see in Google Play Store app).

**I have also searched some posts but this is not my requirement.**

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
2. [Android Search Interface not submitting query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476814/android-search-interface-not-submitting-query)
3. [problems with search interface in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134043/problems-with-search-interface-in-android-app)
4. http://matthias.jimdo.com/2011/06/06/how-to-add-search-functionality-to-your-android-application/

**How can I implement what I actually want to:**

```
############Activity##############

@@Search bar here................@

-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
-------------Result Here----------
```

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from hiding the `ActionBar`, putting your search bar at the top and a content layout(whatever you want) below that search bar.

Comment: Why would you want to use a `Canvas` for displaying searchresults?

Comment: Might be it is I was looking for.

Comment: @Darwind I will show text result in formatted manner.

Comment: `Canvas` is for drawing things - I wouldn't recommend using a `Canvas` for displaying text results and pictures. Use a `ListView` with a custom `Layout` for every item instead. Or a `GridView` for tablets for instance. Don't start with drawing your own things - you'll hate yourself in the end! ;-)

Comment: What do I need if I want to format text and want to display button on the screen. Like if someone will press the button then some action wil l be performed.